# $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n-1}$ question about contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n-1}, n \geq 1$ n integer and let $C_R = \{ R
 e^{it}: 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi \}$ the circle of radius $R$ with center
at 0 traverse once in the anti-clockwise direction, let $I_R = \int_{C_R} f(z) dz$

Now I have problems understanding the following:

If $R > 1$ and $ n \geq 2$ use the ML inequality to show that $I_R = 0$.

> To bound $|f(z)|$ on $C_R$ we have  $ |f(z)| \leq \frac{1}{R^n-1}$, ML
> gives $I_R \leq \frac{2 \pi R}{R^n - 1} = \frac{(2 \pi
> > /R^{n-1})}{1-(1/R)^n} \to 0$ as $ R \to \infty$
>
> (taken from
> [http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~icstmkw/ma3614/exer_ma3614_integrals_some_answers.pdf](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/%7Eicstmkw/ma3614/exer_ma3614_integrals_some_answers.pdf)
> page 3 and 4)

so I do not understand what is happening here isn't

$ \int_{ |z| = R } f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum {\text{Res of singularities of f(z)}}$ ?

They said it is valid for $n \geq 2$, let us take for example $n=2, R >1$ then the simple poles would be at $\pm 1$, would be contained in the circle with $R > 1$ and the sum of the residues would not be 0. So why would the integral be zero? I'll be thankful if someone could explain this.

Comment: Hint: use $w=1/z$ to reduce to a no-residues problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}$Yes, many poles will be contained. No, that doesn't prevent the integral from being zero.

If you want the painful approach, you can calculate the residue sum explicitly (when $R>1$, hence $C_R$ contains all the $n$th roots of unity). For if $\zeta:=\exp(2\pi i/n)$ and $k$ is any integer then: $$\Res_{z=\zeta^k}\frac{1}{z^n-1}=\frac{1}{nz^{n-1}}\Big|_{z=\zeta^k}=\frac{1}{n}\zeta^{k(1-n)}$$

So the contour integral equals: $$\begin{align}2\pi i\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\zeta^{k(1-n)}&=\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(\zeta^{1-n})^k\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot\frac{1-(\zeta^{(1-n)})^n}{1-\zeta^{1-n}}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot\frac{1-(\zeta^n)^{1-n}}{1-\zeta^{1-n}}\\&=\frac{2\pi i}{n}\cdot\frac{1-1^{1-n}}{1-\zeta^{1-n}}\\&=0\end{align}$$

Whenever $R>1$.

However, it is very important to understand that there is nothing wrong with their method. On the region $z\in\Bbb C,\,|z|>1$, $f$ is a holomorphic function. Therefore by the standard theory, so long as $R>1$, the value $\oint_{C_R}f$ is a constant.

In particular, we may take $R$ to be as large as we wish. The ML lemma shows that the complex constant $\oint_{C_R}f$ must then have arbitrarily small modulus, so it must be zero. This is a perfectly fine evaluation.

---

EDIT: To address your comment, here is a picture. I have a path integral from the black spot back to itself (a loop). I can go in the direction of the blue arrows: this would be integrating over $C_R$.

Alternatively, I can go up the purple line, then round following the red circle, and back down the "other" purple line, bringing my back to the black spot. Actually, I am integrating over the same purple line, but I've drawn them in different positions for visual clarity.

These are two contours with the same endpoints, and there is an obvious "homotopy" between them: you just push the outer route, with the red circle, down onto the blue circle (keeping the endpoint, the black mark, fixed). This moves through the domain on which $f$ is holomorphic, so by Cauchy's theorem the two integrals are the same. However, when integrating around the red-and-purple, the integral up the purple line cancels exactly with the integral down it: so, this is numerically equal to just the integral around the red circle.

So, we've shown the integral around either circle (same orientation, note) is the same. Isn't that wonderful? It follows $\oint_{C_R}f$ is a constant in $R>1$.

[image: Picture]

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. Just one question though: you say that "for $ z \in \mathbb{C}, |z| > 1$, f is holomorphic, therefore by standard theory, so long as R > 1, the value $\int_{C_R} f$ is constant" Could you tell me which theorem that is?

Comment: @galaxy-- Well, it's related to Cauchy's theorem, which is basically the theorem of homotopy invariance of contour integrals of holomorphic functions. I'll draw a picture

Comment: thank you so much for the addition and the pic to your answer

Answer (score 2):

If $n=2$, then $f(z)=\frac1{z^2-1}$. So$$\operatorname{res}_{z=1}f(z)=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{z-1}{z^2-1}=\frac12$$and$$\operatorname{res}_{z=-1}f(z)=\lim_{z\to-1}\frac{z+1}{z^2-1}=-\frac12.$$Therefore, the sum of the residues *is* $0$.

Comment: thank you, I just had a stupid sign error then, for me both residues added to 1.